# Running an docker image with cron

Tags: heroku, docker, cron

I am using an image from docker hub and it uses cron to perform some actions after some interval. I have registered and pushed it as described in [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime) as a worker process (not a web). It also requires several environment variables.

I've run it from command line, e.g. `docker run -t -e E_VAR1=VAL1 registry.heroku.com/image_name/worker` and it worked for few days, then suddenly stopped and I had to run the command again.

Questions:

- Is this a correct way to run a docker (as worker process) in Heroku?
- Why might it stop running after few days? Is there any logs to check?
- Is there a way to restart the process automatically?
- How properly set environment variables for the docker in Heroku?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to have this run in the background, you should use the `-d` flag to disconnect stdin and stdout, and not `-t`.
2. To check logs, user `docker logs [container name or id]`. You can find out the container's name and id using `docker ps -a`. That should give you an idea as to why the container stopped.
3. To have the container restart automatically add the `--restart always` flag when you run it. Alternatively, use `--restart on-failure` to only restart when it exited with a nonzero exit code.
4. The way you set environment variables seems fine.